# Why if I'm setting a int variable value to 0 in the top of a script in the inspector the value is 1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();

    public int dialogueNum = 0;
    public int dialogueIndex = 0;
```

After doing Build > Rebuild Solution

dialogueIndex value in the Inspector is 0 but the value of dialogueNum is 1
I never changed it's value in the Inspector. ( Maybe I did and forgot ? )

How can I make sure that the value will be 0 in the Inspector when running the game ? The problem is that before making it public it was hidden so I couldn't see that it's value is 1 in the inspector :

```
[HideInInspector]
public int dialogueNum = 0;

[HideInInspector]
public int dialogueIndex = 0;
```

Now I see that it's value is 1

Comment: That's because the prefab serializes a value for the public variable and that serialized value overrides a default value set in the script. This answer is copied from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/inspector-does-not-update-variables-from-c-script.350871/).

Comment: Yes, you did and forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do initializations in Awake() method and assignments in Start(). This is why these methods made for. So your script should be like:

```
public List<Conversation> conversations;
public int dialogueNum;
public int dialogueIndex;

void Awake(){
   conversations = new List<Conversation>();
}

void Start(){
   dialogueNum = 0;
   dialogueIndex = 0;
}
```

Now the values will be assigned every time you run the game as you wanted.